# Keras model with multiple categorical outputs of different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have a keras model here which looks as follows:
[image: Keras Model]

As you can see, an intent (four classes) is predicted and each word of the sentence is tagged (choce of 10 classes). I'm now struggeling with the model.fit and the y_train data preparation. If I shape it as follows, all works, but it doesn't feel correct as the left output will have the same shape as the right output.

```
x = np.array(df_ic.message)
y = np.zeros((df_ic.message.size,2,85))
```

Can anyone help/suggest how to best shape the train data, i.e. y?

Thanks a lot,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Keras model with 2 outputs and provide (y1, y2) to it.

As an example, please see https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3/blob/main/10_neural_nets_with_keras.ipynb

Search for "Adding an auxiliary output for regularization":

```
"...
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_wide, input_deep],
                       outputs=[output, aux_output])
...
history = model.fit(
    (X_train_wide, X_train_deep), (y_train, y_train), epochs=20,
    validation_data=((X_valid_wide, X_valid_deep), (y_valid, y_valid))
)
..."
```

This is explained in detail in book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 3rd Edition" by Aurélien Géron, see pages 333-335.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. But this doesn't help as the question is not about "how" to add two outputs. It's about the shape of the two outputs (y_valid, y_valid) in your example. I was wondering if there is a way to have different shapes for the two of them. Linking to my initial question, I'd have shape (1,4) for the first and (1,10) for the second y_valid. For now, my solution is to pad the smaller one so it matches the larger ones size.

Comment: Why not just use different shapes for separate outputs? Like: 
out1 = Dense(4)
out2 = Dense(10)
tf.keras.Model(..., outputs=[out1, out2])